# The if else loop executes the else part without condition

Tags: excel, vba

```
(No title)
If Rcount >= 2 Then
    For Rnum = 2 To Rcount
        'Filter the FilterRange on the FieldNum column
        FilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, _
                                   Criteria1:=Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value
        'Look for the mail address in the MailInfo worksheet
        mailAddress = ""
        On Error Resume Next
        mailAddress = ""
        On Error Resume Next
        mailAddress = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
            VLookup(Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value, _
            Worksheets("Mailinfo").Range("A1:C" & _
            Worksheets("Mailinfo").Rows.Count), 3, False
 
        If mailAddress = "" Then               
            Ash.Cells(Rnum, 23) = "Email Missing for " & Ash.Cells(Rnum, 7)
        ElseIf mailAddress <> "" Then
            With Ash.AutoFilter.Range
                On Error Resume Next
                Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                On Error GoTo 0
            End With
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            'On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = mailAddress
                .CC = Str6
                .Subject = Str5
                .HTMLBody = Str1 & Str2 & RangetoHTML(rng) & Str3 & Str4
                .Display  'Or use Display
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            Ash.Cells(Rnum, 23) = "Email Sent"
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        Else
            'Nothing
        End If
        'Close AutoFilter
        Ash.AutoFilterMode = False
    Next Rnum
End If
```

This is a snippet from the ron de bruin's code. Tampered with it a little bit.  The code executes the else part even if the mail address are present in the sheet.

Also if there are multiple cells with the same name. It does not paste the sent email message on every cell.

Comment: Whenever you are debugging your code, remove `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: There is a bracket missing from the line `mailAddress = Application.WorksheetFunction. _ ...`

Comment: The missing bracket is a typo. Doing this from a mobile phone. Also, after removing the "on error resume next" it throws "Run-time error '1004'

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: mailAddress = ""
        On Error Resume Next
        mailAddress = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
            VLookup(Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value, _
            Worksheets("Mailinfo").Range("A1:C" & _
            Worksheets("Mailinfo").Rows.Count), 3, False) if i debug this is the part that throws 1004 which i believe is due to the missing values in Vlookup and if i run using error handlers then it throws that error at random fields without proper relevance.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full answer or solution, because I don't think we have enough information to really pinpoint your problem. But I do strongly recommend creating separate lines and intermediate variables. For example, your statement:

```
    mailAddress = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
        VLookup(Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value, _
        Worksheets("Mailinfo").Range("A1:C" & _
        Worksheets("Mailinfo").Rows.Count), 3, False
```

Can fail in a number of ways, and it's VERY difficult to figure out why.

It costs absolutely nothing in terms of memory or speed of execution, and GREATLY enhances the readability (and the ability to debug) of your program if you create intermediate variables. Such as:

```
Dim findThis As String
findThis = Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).value

Dim mailInfo As Worksheet
Set mailInfo = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Mailinfo")
With mailInfo
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim inThisRange As Range
    Set inThisRange = mailInfo.Range("A1:C" & lastRow)
End With

Dim mailAddress As String
mailAddress = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
                  VLookup(findThis, inThisRange, 3, False)
```

While I'm guessing here, you can now check the values of `findThis`, `lastRow`, and `inThisRange.Address` to validate that your code is actually looking in the correct range.

Do this for most of the other parts of your code as well (make it a habit!) and it should help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Tho, i have decided to manually vlookup the values in the sheet needed and have the script get the value from the same page. It has now eliminated the whole code and the need for vlookup in the code.